# set backcolor to disabled button windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms, button, background-color

I have a button in my windows forms which I need to enable/disable. When disabled I need to change its backcolor and retain the forecolor to show that it is disabled.

Following is what I tried. this retains the forecolor(white here), but does not change the backcolor

```
private void button1_EnabledChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {          
        buttonScan.ForeColor = Color.White;   
        buttonScan.BackColor = Color.Aqua;              
    }

private void button1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        var btn = (Button)sender;
        var drawBrush = new SolidBrush(btn.ForeColor);
        var sf = new StringFormat { Alignment = StringAlignment.Center, LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center};                       
        e.Graphics.DrawString(btn.Text, btn.Font, drawBrush, e.ClipRectangle, sf);                    
        drawBrush.Dispose();
        sf.Dispose();
    }
```

I need to change the backcolor when the button is disabled

Answer (score 0):

f you want to use your custom color, you need to set UseVisualStyleBackColor to false or the color will only be applied to the button upon mouse over.

a simple test uploaded to [GitHub](https://github.com/balexandre/StacOverflow-Question-7127946)

```
public partial class mainForm : Form
{
Random randonGen = new Random();

public mainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void mainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    populate();
}

private void populate()
{
    Control[] buttonsLeft = createButtons().ToArray();
    Control[] buttonsRight = createButtons().ToArray();

    pRight.Controls.AddRange(buttonsRight);
    pLeft.Controls.AddRange(buttonsLeft);
}

private List<Button> createButtons()
{
    List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {

        buttons.Add(
            new Button()
            {
                Size = new Size(200, 35),
                Enabled = true,
                BackColor = GetColor(),
                ForeColor = GetColor(),
                UseVisualStyleBackColor = false,
                Left = 20,
                Top = (i * 40),
                Text = String.Concat("Button ", i)
            });
    }

    return buttons;
}

private Color GetColor()
{
    return Color.FromArgb(randonGen.Next(255), randonGen.Next(255), randonGen.Next(255));
}
}
```