Change TextColor of disabled button (failed after following suggested answer)
After reading
Change TextColor of disabled control, I follow Hans Olsson's answer.

However, if you want to do it properly you need to make them Owner-draw or override the OnPaint event and draw the text yourself.

So, I wrote the function:
private void button_resetRelay3_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("button_resetRelay3_Paint");
    if (true == comboBox_F3OnOffParam.Text.ToUpper().Equals("ON"))
    {
        button_setRelay3.ForeColor = Color.White;
        Debug.WriteLine("Color.White");
    }
    else
    {
        button_setRelay3.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlText;
        Debug.WriteLine("Color.ControlText");
    }
}

Despite that I always have the ForeColor as gray despite the Debug.WriteLine("Color.White"); is correctly displayed. Note, the Button is disabled. No problem to change color when the Button is enabled.
Do you have any suggestion?

Setting the ForeColor property does not mean you are drawing anything. Also, you're implementing the Paint event and not overriding the OnPaint method. You need to create a custom button, override the OnPaint method to draw it all. Google for ButtonRenderer and TextRenderer examples.

Can you explain a little better what you're trying to do here? Do you need to change the color of the text of a Button, when some condition changes (a selection is made using a ComboBox, here)? Why the Paint event then? Why not the SelectionChangeCommited event of the ComboBox, or with DataBindings? + Are these two different Buttons? One named button_resetRelay3 and the other button_setRelay3? All this just because one of the affected Buttons is disabled? How is this Button configured (its style etc.)? Are VisualStyles enabled?

Thanks for your answer Jimi, The FlatStyle is set Standard and it does not work when I try to change the ForeColor of the button when the button is disable. (comboBox_F3OnOffParam.Text is On or Off, depending of comboBox_F3OnOffParam.Text I would like to set button_setRelay3.ForeColor White or Color.ControlText). I am using Microsoft Visual Studio.

I also tried dr.null solution as shown in post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23825819/set-backcolor-to-disabled-button-windows-forms?rq=2 but same result that in the post: it does not change the ForeColor

Found this one on google. Completely forgot about it. Note the text drawing parts in the first example (e.Graphics.DrawString and TextRenderer.DrawText), set there the required disabled foreground color. Give it a try.

Here's a lightweight extended class that uses ControlPaint.DrawButton to render the blank button so that you can cleanly draw the colored text over it.

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (Enabled)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
    else
    {
        var buttonState = Enabled ? ButtonState.Normal : ButtonState.Inactive;
        ControlPaint.DrawButton(e.Graphics, ClientRectangle, buttonState);

        Color textColorWithTransparency = 
            Color.FromArgb(
                0xA0,                   
                ForeColorDisabled);
                
        using (var brush = new SolidBrush(textColorWithTransparency))
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(
                Text,
                Font,
                brush,
                ClientRectangle,
                new StringFormat
                {
                    Alignment = StringAlignment.Center,
                    LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
                });
        }
    }
}

You can set the disabled fore color in the designer:


You will want to manually change instances of Button in the designer to instances of ButtonEx.


